# Welche Wortart ist »wie« in »wie folgt«?

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun, conjunction, grammar-identification, word-classes

Was ist die allgemein anerkannte grammatische Analysis von »wie« wie in »wie folgt« oder im folgenden Auszug aus *Das Schloß* von Kafka:

> Aus einer großen Luke, der einzigen in der Stubenrückwand, kam dort, wohl vom Hof her, bleiches Schneelicht und gab dem Kleid einer Frau, die tief in der Ecke in einem hohen Lehnstuhl müde fast lag, einen Schein wie von Seide. Sie trug einen Säugling an der Brust. Um sie herum spielten paar Kinder, Bauernkinder **wie** zu sehen war, sie aber schien nicht zu ihnen zu gehören, freilich, Krankheit und Müdigkeit macht auch Bauern fein.

Sagt man, dass »wie« eine Konjunktion sei, und dass dem Satz ein Subjekt fehle?

Oder dass »wie« ein Pronomen und das Subjekt des Satz sei?

(Auf Englisch hätte ich gesagt »grammatical account« oder »treatment« da »analysis« schwerfällig ist.  Reformulieren Sie die Frage wenn ein anderes Deutsches Wort besser klingt.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...Bauernkinder, wie zu sehen war...

(ich habe ein Komma eingefügt, weil ich es für notwendig halte) ist ein *[Relativsatz](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Attribut/index.html)*, der ausnahmsweise nicht um ein *Relativpronomen*, sondern um ein *Relativadverb* ("wie") geformt ist.

Relativadverbien werden zur Satzbildung genommen, um Relativsätze, die *temporale*, *lokale*, und (wie hier) *modale* Zusammenhänge, die sich mit normalen Relativpronomen (*der, die, das, welcher,...*) nicht ausdrücken lassen, zu formulieren.

Der Relativsatz bezieht sich natürlich auf die *Bauernkinder* und beschreibt den Eindruck, den sie machen, näher.

Das "wie" in diesem Satz ist also weder ein Pronomen noch eine Konjunktion, sondern ein **Adverb**.

Comment: Danke! Dann der Relativesatz ist subjektlos? Gibt es andere Relativadverbien als »wie«?

Comment: Ja, ich würde sagen, das ist ein freier Relativsatz. Andere Relativadverbien könne alle Frageworter (*wie, warum, wieso, wann, wo, ...) sein, und ein paar teilweise veraltete Sonderfälle wie *da*. Eine gute Grammatik sollte eine einigermaßen vollständige Liste haben.